# Keep page in navigation hierarchy in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am doing a wp8.1 runtime app.
I have my page structure like below

```
MainPage 
     -> Page1
     -> Page2
     -> Page3
     -> Page4
        ..
```

Question is why page1 is deleted in the Fram navigation hierarchy, when I navigate from page1 back to MainPage. and again from MainPage to page1 is creating a new page(NavigationMode is set to new).

Is there a way to prevent those once opened/created page being removed? Or doing this is not a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to cache the page.

Unless your page contains loads of data, you shouln't really cache it. For example a panorama page with a lot of data displayed to the user might take a while to reload each time, so caching might be useful here. But for the case of a simple page, caching isn't really used, the OS handles this well.

Depending on your needs, adjust the constructor of the page with the following piece of code :

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

or

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

You can control how many pages to cache using the `CacheSize` property of your rootFrame.

Comment: Hey @Vasile Marian Falamas I have made it enabled, but when I get back to mainpage the dictionary in pagestate is still deleted, and NavigationCacheMode is set to disable again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using NavigationHelper to obtain state, right?
It removes the state when NavigationMode is New.

You can either change the behavior in the NavigationHelper class (in Common) or create an own mechanism for saving the state.